# When I try to start neo4j console i see exception stating java 11 required

Tags: neo4j

When I try to run neo4j console I encountered below exception, I'm using `java 1.8`.

```
WARNING: ERROR! Neo4j cannot be started using java version 1.8.0_121 WARNING: * Please use Oracle(R) Java(TM) 11, OpenJDK(TM) 11 to run Neo4j Server.
* Please see https://neo4j.com/docs/ for Neo4j installation instructions. Invoke-Neo4j : This instance of Java is not supported At C:\Dev\neo4j-community-4.1.0-windows\neo4j-community-4.1.0\bin\neo4j.ps1:29 char:7
+ Exit (Invoke-Neo4j -Verbose:$Arguments.Verbose -Command $Arguments.Ar ...
+       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException<br/>
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : \>Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Invoke-Neo4j
```

Do I need to switch to `java 11`? Any help appreciated.

Comment: Yep, you need java 11 to run Neo4j

Comment: That helped, after I set openjdk 11 as java home neo4j started without any issues

Answer (score 1):

As neo4j 4.x's [software requirements](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/installation/requirements/#deployment-requirements-software) state, a supported version of JDK 11 is required.